# Script not working - error reporting turned on but still getting white screen

Tags: php, mysql

So i am working on the following script, just a 'simple' gathering of form data - popping it into the database then happy days! for some reason I am just getting a blank page - despite having error reporting turned on - its driving me crazy! - any ideas? Thank you so much in advance for your help.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}





session_start();
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../main');

    die();
}


    //! Checks if the user type is admin full

 if ($_SESSION['type'] === 'admin-full') 
    {



    $comp_name = $_POST['comp_name'];
    $comp_number = $_POST['comp_number'];
    $vat_number = $_POST['vat_number'];
    $add1 = $_POST['add1'];
    $add2 = $_POST['add2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $branch_name = $_POST['branch_name'];
    $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];


    //! Real_escape the form data

    $comp_name =        mysql_real_escape_string($comp_name);
    $comp_number =      mysql_real_escape_string($comp_number);
    $vat_number =       mysql_real_escape_string($vat_number);
    $add1 =             mysql_real_escape_string($add1);
    $add2 =             mysql_real_escape_string($add2);
    $city =             mysql_real_escape_string($city);
    $postcode =         mysql_real_escape_string($postcode);
    $branch_name =      mysql_real_escape_string($branch_name);
    $contact_name =     mysql_real_escape_string($contact_name);
    $contact_number=    mysql_real_escape_string($contact_number);

    //! MySQL Query

    require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php');
    mysql_select_db($database_PropSuite, $PropSuite);

    $query = "INSERT INTO franchises 

    (comp_name, comp_number, vat_number, add1, add2, city, postcode, branch_name, contact_name, contact_number )

    VALUES 
    ('$comp_name', '$comp_number', '$vat_number', '$add1', '$add2', '$city', '$postcode', '$branch_name', '$contact_name', '$contact_number');";



    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_close();


    header(location:'franchise-new.php?success');




}

else {
    echo('You need to be an admin user to do that!, If you are seeing this message in error, please contact the system administrator.');
}


?>
```

Comment: Detect last executed line of code using `var_dump('any_value');exit;` (or use debugging if you can). Additionally you have to set error reporting level to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for debuging purposes.

Comment: but what about your php.ini file? if it set as a production environment the line `display_errors` will be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your successful MySQL command, you have this command:

```
header(location:'franchise-new.php?success');
```

This should be quoted entirely. Otherwise nothing will load, but you will not be redirected.

```
header('location: franchise-new.php?success');
```

Comment: Fantastic that worked - I think it was a classic case of not being able to see for looking! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally Location headers should use an absolute URI (i.e. `http://example.com/somewhere/main`). Otherwise are you certain that this:

```
header('Location: ../main');
```

Points to a valid file? Try adding echo statements after the header calls to narrow done the branch of code you are in.